# Disable table with ASP.net controls & Telerik controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, telerik

MY TABLE:

```
<table id="DispalyTable" border="4px"  style="width: 100%;"  >
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 137px; height: 137px;" valign="top">
                                <telerik:RadGrid runat="server">
                                    <MasterTableView>
                                        <Columns>
                                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Checked="true" Text="ALL" />
                                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server"  />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </MasterTableView>
                                </telerik:RadGrid>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 130px;" valign="top">
                                <div>
                                    <input id="Alloption" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="All" onchange="javascript:othercheckboxalloption();" style="color: Black" 
                                        /><span style="color: Black">All </span>
                                    <br />
                                    <input id="otherCheckbox2" type="checkbox" value="Accepted" style="color: Black"
                                        class="chkdisplay" onchange="javascript:othercheckbxdisplay();"  /><span style="color: Black">Accepted </span>
                                    <br />
                                    <input id="otherCheckbox3" type="checkbox" value="Contracted" style="color: Black"
                                        class="chkdisplay" onchange="javascript:othercheckbxdisplay();" /><span style="color: Black">Contracted</span>
                                    <br />
                                    <input id="otherCheckbox4" type="checkbox" value="Pending" style="color: Black" class="chkdisplay"  onchange="javascript:othercheckbxdisplay();" /><span
                                        style="color: Black">Pending</span>
                                    <br />
                                    <input id="otherCheckbox5" type="checkbox" value="Pre-Authorized" style="color: Black"
                                        class="chkdisplay" onchange="javascript:othercheckbxdisplay();"  /><span style="color: Black">Pre-Authorized</span>
                                    <br />
                                    <input id="otherCheckbox6" type="checkbox" value="Show Deleted" style="color: Black"
                                        class="chkdisplay" onchange="javascript:othercheckbxdisplay();"  /><span style="color: Black">Show Deleted</span>
                                    <br />
                                    <input id="otherCheckbox7" type="checkbox" value="Treated" style="color: Black" class="chkdisplay"  onchange="javascript:othercheckbxdisplay();"  /><span
                                        style="color: Black">Treated</span>
                                    <br />
                                    <%-- <asp:CheckBox ID="All" runat="server" Checked="true" Text="ALL" ForeColor="Black"  /><br />

                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 138px;" valign="top">
                                <div>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox8" runat="server" Checked="true" Text="Accepted" ForeColor="Black" /><br />
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox9" runat="server" Checked="false" Text="Appointment" ForeColor="Black" /><br />
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox10" runat="server" Checked="true" Text="Contract #" ForeColor="Black" /><br />
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox11" runat="server" Checked="true" Text="Pre-Auth #" ForeColor="Black" /><br />
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox12" runat="server" Checked="true" Text="TX Coloums" ForeColor="Black" /><br />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <div>

                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" >
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Diag Date,Tth,Proc" Value="Diag Date,Tth,Proc"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Tth,Diag Date,Proc" Value="Tth,Diag Date,Proc"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Code I Tried:

```
 function notewizardcheckbox() {
            $("#DispalyTable").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
```

control on  which the above function is called, `onchange` event

```
<div style=" margin-left:25px; margin-top:17px; float:none;">
                <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="Note Wizard View"  onchange="javascript:notewizardcheckbox();"  /><span
                                    style="color: Blue; font-size:21px; margin-left:6px;" >Note Wizard View</span>
                </div>
```

Comment: When you say "disable table", do you mean "disable all form elements inside that table"? (Actual `<table>` elements don't really have a concept of disabled or enabled.)

Comment: @nnnnnYes disable all content in table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable all form controls in the table you can do this:

```
$('#DispalyTable :input').prop('disabled', true);
```

The [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) will select input, textarea, select and button elements.

If the Telerik / .Net controls are not "normal" html form elements but they have a `disabled` property then you could try this:

```
$('#DispalyTable td').find('*').prop('disabled', true);
```

That is, select *all* of the elements within the cells of the table and set `disabled` to `true` (even though that may not make sense for some of them).

Comment: I tried but only the controls with input gets disabled but not my telerik and asp.net controls

Comment: Thank u for ur rply.you are saying right but how can i disable telerik,asp.net controls.Is there no way of directly disabling the whole Table at once

Comment: Are you saying my second suggestion doesn't work? `<table>` elements don't have a concept of "disabled", so you have to select the elements within the table and disable them on an individual basis (jQuery gives you shortcuts to select them as a group as shown in my answer, but inside the jQuery code it loops over them all applying the disabled property to them individually).

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery will disable all input element inside '#DispalyTable' div.

```
$('#DispalyTable input').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

Comment: I tried but only the controls with input gets disabled but not my telerik and asp.net controls

Comment: Can you look into/share the rendered html for your telerik & asp.net controls which are causing problem?

Comment: Is there no way of directly disabling the whole Table at once